# React FilePond: Display an image using url

Tags: reactjs, image, display, filepond

My plan is to render an image using url when the Filepond component is rendered. Take note that ***this is not*** about a preview after a file is added.

I guess *'file poster'* can help with this concern. But I don't have an idea yet if it is useful. Here is a sample code below.

```js
    const [file, setFile] = useState({
        source: '12345', //i am not sure
        options: {
             type: 'local',
             file: {
                 name: 'hedgehog.jpg',
                 size: 189397, 
                 type: 'image/jpeg'
             },
            metadata: {
                poster: 'http://localhost:3000/uploads/5e5b3895e1ee0b2128aa9eaa_hedgehog.jpg'
            }
        }
    })

        <Uploader
            //acceptedFileTypes={mimeTypes}
            ref={ref => pond = ref}
            file={file}
            allowFileSizeValidation={true}
            maxFileSize="50mb"
            instantUpload={false}
            name='items'
            allowMultiple={false}
            allowFilePoster={true}
            labelIdle='Drag & Drop files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
            server={`${apiBaseUrl}api/uploads/`}
        />
```

Anyone have the idea on how to load a url?
I am using Filepond in React

Comment: Did you solve this?